# How to i fix a firestore error complaining about order by on equality filter

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This works

```
collection
    .where('startDate', '>=', startDate)
    .get();
```

This will cause an error

```
collection
    .where('startDate', '>=', startDate)
    .where('startDate', '<=', endDate)
    .get();
```

The error 
`Error: order by clause cannot contain a field with an equality filter startDate`

I don't understand the error or how to fix it. My data type in firestore is a date. The documentation allows for range queries as long as its the same field so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the startDate / endDate variables was an integer and once i changed it to a date object the query starts working.

Answer (score 3):

If startDate and endDate are same, you will also get that error, e.g.:

```
    let startDate = new Date('1980-12-01')
    let endDate = new Date('1980-12-01')
```

Solution is:

```
    let startDate = new Date('1980-12-01 00:00:00')
    let endDate = new Date('1980-12-01 23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 1):

I had got the same error because I was using the exact same string at both where clauses

```
.where("field", ">=", "somestring").where("field", "<=", "somestring")
```

My code was:

```
let boxSearch = document.getElementById("boxSearch").value;

dbRef.collection("clients").where("name", ">=", boxSearch).where("name", "<=", boxSearch).get()
```

The solution for me, was use "somestring" + "~" on the second where clause as follow:

```
dbRef.collection("clients").where("name", ">=", boxSearch).where("name", "<=", boxSearch + "~").get()
```

OR

```
dbRef.collection("clients").orderBy("name").startAt(boxSearch).endAt(boxSearch + "~").get()
```

Answer (score 0):

if The Same field for order by and where equal.it's should not Boolean field.actually it's not necessary right.because if you add equals you get either true or false..that's why getting error..

Ex:

```
Firestore firestore_db = getFirestoreInstance();
Query query=firestore_db.collection("collection").orderBy("isAllow",Direction.DESCENDING).whereEqualTo("isAllow", false);
```

if your query above. it won't work..